# Using Calculate Field for If statement over many fields?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

[image]

I'm struggling with the python syntax in the Calculate Field so that, in the table above:

**if b, c, d, or e are NOT NULL populate the Summary field with "Verified"
else populate Summary field with "In Progress"**

So if any of the B, C, D or E columns contain NULL the Summary field will read "In Progress".

I believe this should be something along the lines of:

`def Reclass !SUMMARY!:
    if [ !B! , !C! , !D! , !E!]  <> NULL
        !SUMMARY! = "Verified: "
    else
        !SUMMARY! = "In Progress: "`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the field calc on the Summary field. Use Python as the parser and check the Show Codeblock box.

For the Pre-Logic Script Code put:

```
def Reclass(B, C, D, E):
    if None not in (B, C, D, E) and "" not in (B, C, D, E):
        return "Verified"
    else:
        return "In Progess"
```

Then put this in the bottom box:

```
Reclass(!B!, !C!, !D!, !E!)
```

The bottom box with the ! contains the actual field names that get passed into the Reclass function in the top box.

I included the `"" not in (B, C, D, E)` as a check specifically for text fields that are blank but don't have the Null value, if you need it.

Comment: @Simon Good to hear!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not meant to steal from [@ian](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/12159/ian), but it shows a little bit easier way to write the code that he provided...  instead of using a code block (which can be a pain in the butt sometimes when trying to write it in a standalone script...) you can rewrite his code in a single line as:

```
"Verified" if None not in (!B!, !C!, !D!, !E!) and "" not in (!B!, !C!, !D!, !E!) else "In Progress"
```